# Ubuntu 20.04 minimal say "Failed to install based"

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, ubuntu-minimal

I am trying to install both Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04. Both report an error during the installation:

- 18.04 ⇢ `unstable network`
- 20.04 ⇢ `The base system installation into /target/ failed.`

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a netinst image? If so, the netinst images use your network to install. You can try a different image instead.

Comment: Did you had link for other image, cuz I using netboot dir for the mini.iso...

Comment: Retry with http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/mini.iso and stable ethernet connection.